# Attempting to load external file in Javascript with Dojo: file not found

Tags: javascript, dojo

As a test, I'm loading in a file in my javascript code using Dojo:

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/request", "dojo/json", "dojo/_base/array", "dojo/domReady!"],
function (dom, request, JSON, arrayUtil) {

    request("TextFile1.txt").then(
        function (text) {
            console.log("The file's contents is: " + text);
        },
         function (error) {
             console.log("An error occurred: " + error);
         }
     );
}
);
```

The text tile is in the same directory as the script, but I get a 404 Not Found error. I've also tried putting this file on our development server and using the URL for the file, but get the same error. Why can't this code locate the file?

This is a VS2012 project.

EDIT

After trying several different tests, this code suddenly works properly. It's not giving a Not Found error when requesting the file, even though I'm using the same line

```
request("TextFile1.txt").then(
```

Very strange....

Comment: Perhaps there's a default path set? Check for network errors in the console. (and/or try ".\textfile.txt")

Comment: Try giving a path from the http root which starts with / or the same as http://website/TextFile1.txt . TextFile1.txt needs to be in a path accessible by the user's web browser.  If still not found, check permissions on the file (Viewable by all??)